# Como executar um comando php dinamicamente durante a execução do programa

Tags: php, aplicação-web, select

Estou fazendo uma aplicação **web** que exibe um stream de camêra, porém sempre que vou utiliza-la, é necessário recarregar a página, e eu preciso que isso aconteça automaticamente.

Minha idéia é executar dinamicamente uma consulta no banco utilizando o **php**, para a página atualizar quando o valor do campo *dial* for igual a "0".

Minha tentativa foi a seguinte:

```
    <?php
     $sql = "select dial from ipstream where idusuario = '7';";
            while(true)
            {
                $retorno = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
                $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retorno);
                if($linha['dial'] == "1")
                {
                    $sql = "update ipstream set dial = '0' where idusuario = '7';";

                    mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

                    echo "<script>location.reload();</script>";
                }
            }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao invés de utilizar o PHP para acionar javascript, faça o inverso, utilize o javascript/jquery para acionar o PHP. E ao invés de recarregar toda página, recarregue apenas o conteúdo.

Comment: Eu consigo fazer isso utilizando um AJAX certo?

Comment: perfeitamente!!!